# How we do object property assignment based on condition while constructing the js object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

i am using lodash _.map, trying to assign variable value based on condition so in below code i want to call convertPrice only when we have object in oldDrugPrice.mailPrice. How do we achieve this task ?

Dont want to add mailPrice in the object if oldDrugPrice does not have mailPrice.

main.js

```
return _.map(cvsResponse, function(oldDrugPrice) {
    return {
      isBrand:        oldDrugPrice.brand,
      drugForm:       capitalizeWords(oldDrugPrice.drugForm),
      mailPrice:      convertPrice(oldDrugPrice.mailPrice, version),
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the object first and add the property if condition is true, then return the object

```
return _.map(cvsResponse, function(oldDrugPrice) {

  const obj = {
    isBrand: oldDrugPrice.brand,
    drugForm: capitalizeWords(oldDrugPrice.drugForm)
  };

  if (typeof oldDrugPrice.mailPrice === 'object') {
    obj.mailPrice = convertPrice(oldDrugPrice.mailPrice, version),
  }
  return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spread with a logical short circuit. If `oldDrugPrice.mailPrice` is not `undefined` it will spread the the object with the `mailPrice` prop, and it will be added to the final object. If `_.isUndefined()` returns `true`, the empty object would be applied instead.

```
_.map(cvsResponse, function(oldDrugPrice) {
  return {
    isBrand: oldDrugPrice.brand,
    drugForm: capitalizeWords(oldDrugPrice.drugForm),
    ..._.isUndefined(oldDrugPrice.mailPrice) ? 
        {} : { mailPrice: convertPrice(oldDrugPrice.mailPrice, version) },
  };
})
```